# Is there a possibility to sort a bibliography by language/author/title?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, sorting

For getting the list of bibliography with `biblatex` I use this code:

```
...
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources principaux}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword={primary,ncite},heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources secondaires}]
....
```

I use different types of bib-entries like `@Book`, `@Article`, `@Misc`, `@Incollection`, `@Inproceedings`, etc. I would like to sort the bibliography

1. by language in this order: French, German, English, Polish, Greek, Russian
2. by the author’s surname
3. by title (because a lot of entries do not have an author’s name)

Is there a possibility to get this type of sorting for every subbibliography title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several aspects to this.

1. The language ordering is best done by a bibliography filter since you don't really want it sorted by the value of the "language" field I assume (`biblatex` manual 3.5.9)
2. and 3. You can define custom sorting specifications, see section 4.5.1 of the `biblatex` manual.

It seems though that you also might need different sorting specifications for different `\printbibliography` commands. This is currently not possible but is almost implemented (for `biblatex`/Biber) and will be released probably in `biblatex` 2.0/Biber 1.0 which isn't too far away.

Comment: So, how should #1 be implemented? I assume it's about filtering based on the `language` field and then printing relevant parts to a single bibliography, correct?

Comment: Actually, the trick is only to get the language sort to go in a specific order (not alphabetical). I would use `\DeclareSourcemap` to match the `langid`, `hyphenation` or `language` field ( whchever has the most consistent information) and then use this to set the `usera` field with an alphabetic letter in the right order. Then define a custom sort scheme which sorts on `usera` first. This is the best way to get specific non-alphabetic sorts for one field in a sort scheme.