# How to sort bibliographic entries such that first goes such that their field's value equal to certain one?

Tags: biblatex, koma-script

I have the following bib.text:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@article{article1,
  author       = {Автор, И. О.},
  date         = {2020},
  journaltitle = {Супер-пупер крутой журнал},
  language     = {russian},
  number       = {38},
  pages        = {100 -- 105},
  title        = {{Статья некоторого автора на некоторую тему в некотором журнале}},
  volume       = {107},
}

@article{CHEREMISIN201326,
  author   = {Cheremisin, A. A. and Kushnarenko, A. V.},
  doi      = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaerosci.2013.03.011},
  issn     = {0021-8502},
  journal  = {Journal of Aerosol Science},
  language = {english},
  pages    = {26 -- 39},
  title    = {Photophoretic interaction of aerosol particles and its effect on coagulation in rarefied gas medium},
  url      = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021850213000724},
  volume   = {62},
  year     = {2013}
}

@article{CHEREMISIN201915,
  author   = {Cheremisin, A. A.},
  doi      = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaerosci.2019.05.005},
  issn     = {0021-8502},
  journal  = {Journal of Aerosol Science},
  keywords = {Aerosol, Photophoresis, Nonuniform accommodation, Atmosphere, Gravito-photophoresis},
  language = {english},
  pages    = {15 - 35},
  title    = {Photophoresis of aerosol particles with nonuniform gas–surface accommodation in the free molecular regime},
  url      = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021850218301393},
  volume   = {136},
  year     = {2019}
}
```

In bibliography, I wanna show firstly entries with language russian and after entries sorted by their language names.

Stub:

```
\documentclass{scrreport}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addglobalbib{bib.bib}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{ltny}{
\sort[direction=descending]{
\field{language}
}
\sort{
    \field{title}
    \field{author}
    \field{year}
}
}

\begin{document}
\newrefcontext{ltny}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268384/35864 help? Specifically, the second part of the answer that suggests a sourcemap approach to populate `presort`? (You may have to adjust the idea from `langid` to `language`.)

Comment: Yes, thanks very much!