# What does the `final` option of biblatex's DeclareSourcemap do?

Tags: biblatex

**A BibTeX document**

The following BibTeX code is saved in `~/TestBib.bib`.

```
@book{shakespeare,
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   title = {Hamlet},
   year = {1600},
   langid = {english}
}
@book{homer,
   author = {Homer},
   title = {Illiad \& Oddysey},
   year = {8th century BC},
   langid = {greek}
}
@book{tolstoy,
   author = {Leo Tolstoy},
   title = {War and Peace},
   year = {1869},
   langid = {russian}
}
```

---

**A simple LaTeX document with a bibliography**

The following LaTeX code is saved in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{TestBib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{shakespeare}\cite{homer}\cite{tolstoy}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result of running

> > cd ~
> > lualatex Test
> > biber Test
> > lualatex Test

is

[image: Untampered]

---

**English first, Russian second**

We shall now add a source map to order the bibliographic entries in such a way that the English entry is first, and the Russian entry is second.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap {
   \maps {
      \map {
         \step [
            fieldsource=langid,
            match=english,
            fieldset=presort,
            fieldvalue=a
         ]
         \step [
            fieldsource=langid,
            match=russian,
            fieldset=presort,
            fieldvalue=b
         ]
      }
   }
}
\addbibresource{TestBib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{shakespeare}\cite{homer}\cite{tolstoy}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is as expected:

[image: English first, Russian second]

**Adding `final` to the first step**

If we now add the option `final` to the first `step`, as follows:

```
         \step [
            fieldsource=langid,
            match=english,
            fieldset=presort,
            fieldvalue=a,
            final
         ]
```

The output is:

[image: With the "final" option]

Note that the Russian entry is no longer second.

---

**Question**

Why does the addition of the `final` option change the order of the bibliographic entries?

What I expected this option to do is merely improve the efficiency of the processing: once the first `step` matches the English entry, the `final` option would cause the second `step` to be skipped, whereas without the `final` option, the second `step` would have `russian` tested against the entry even if it has already matched against `english`.

Comment: If the second `step` is skipped then the sort order for the Russian entry would be the normal sort order, i.e., by author last name, and therefore third (Tolstoy after Homer), right?

Comment: @Marijn Right. If it is *always* skipped, or equivalently if it is physically deleted from the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `final` keyword stops processing of the current `\map` after the `\step` where it is used if the 'precondition' of the current step is not met.

| Step | `final` terminates if |
| --- | --- |
| `typeseource=<type>,` | current entry is not of type `<type>` |
| `fieldsource=<field>,` | field `<field>` is not present |
| `notfield=<field>,` | field `<field>` *is* present |
| `fieldsource=<field>, match=<regexp>,` | field `<field>` does not match the regular expression `<regexp>` |
| `fieldset=<field>,` | `<field>` is already present and `overwrite` is `false` |

The `final` in

```
  \step[
    fieldsource=langid,
    match=english,
    fieldset=presort,
    fieldvalue=a,
    final
  ]
```

triggers the `fieldsource=<field>, match=<regexp>,` case here, which means that the `\map` is aborted for entries whose `langid` field does not match `english`. This is the case for both `homer` and `tolstoy`. So both of those entry do not get their `presort` value set (which means the value falls back to `mm`).

Comment: Thank you. This is very clear! Are you a developer of the *biblatex* package? If so, the table from your answer should be part of the manual. The manual is both unclear and misleading about the semantics of `final`. The following sentence from the manual suggests that `final` aborts the current `map` when the match *succeeds*, which is what led to my confusion:

Comment: "If fieldset is defined, then its value is 〈entryfield〉 which will be set to a value specified by further options. If overwrite is false for this step and the field to set already exists then the map step is ignored. If final is also true for this step, then processing of the parent map stops at this point." (p. 203 of the current version, 3.18b, July 12, 2022).

Comment: I have created [a ticket in `biblatex`'s bug-tracking list](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1253) for improving the manual's explanation of `final` .