# How to sort a biblatex bibliography by language, as indicated by a field in the bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, sorting, multilingual

The following question is a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14886/21685), but the duplicate has never received a fleshed out answer, and it was asked and answered 11 years ago.

---

The following LaTeX document was saved in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{TestBib.bib}
\begin{document}
First English citation~\cite{einstein}.
First Gibberish citation~\cite{vierstein}.
Second English citation~\cite{zweistein}.
Second Gibberish citation~\cite{fuenfstein}.
Third English citation~\cite{dreistein}. 
Third Gibberish citation~\cite{sechsstein}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The following BibTex listing was saved in `~/TestBib.bib`.

```
@book{einstein,
   author = "Albert Einstein",
   title = "First In, First Out",
   year = 1900,
   langid = english
}
@book{zweistein,
   author = "Balbert Zweistein",
   title = "Always the Bridegroom, Never the Bride",
   year = 1950,
   langid = english
}
@book{dreistein,
   author = "Calbert Dreistein",
   title = "Three Is Company",
   year = 2000,
   langid = english
}
@book{vierstein,
   author = "Calbert Einstein",
   title = "First In, First Out (Gibberish Edition)",
   year = 1900,
   langid = gibberish
}
@book{fuenfstein,
   author = "Albert Zweistein",
   title = "Always the Bridegroom, Never the Bride (Gibberish Edition)",
   year = 1950,
   langid = gibberish
}
@book{sechsstein,
   author = "Balbert Dreistein",
   title = "Three Is Company (Gibberish Edition)",
   year = 2000,
   langid = gibberish
}
```

The following four commands were then executed in the Terminal.

```
\> cd ~  
\> lualatex Test  
\> biber Test  
\> lualatex Test
```

All executions completed successfully, and at the end the file `~/Test.pdf` has come into existence. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows. (Only the relevant part of the display is captured in the screenshot.)

[image: A simple article with a bilingual bibliography]

How can I set things up so that the bibliography will be ordered in such a way that the entries whose `langid` is `gibberish` will be listed before the `english` entries? (Each language group should be sorted according to the normal ordering, which seems to be: surname, first name, title.)

**An attempt**

Following [Ulrike Fischer's advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666182/how-to-sort-a-biblatex-bibliography-by-language-as-indicated-by-a-field-in-the#comment1656433_666182) I tried defining a sorting template as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=sample]{biblatex}
\DeclareSortingTemplate{sample}{ \sort[direction=descending]{ \field{langid} } }
\addbibresource{TestBib.bib}
\begin{document}
First English citation~\cite{einstein}.
First Gibberish citation~\cite{vierstein}.
Second English citation~\cite{zweistein}.
Second Gibberish citation~\cite{fuenfstein}.
Third English citation~\cite{dreistein}. 
Third Gibberish citation~\cite{sechsstein}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bibliography of the resulting PDF file displayed as follows.

[image: DeclareSortingTemplate]

There are two problems with this output.

1. It is not ordered according to the `langid` field despite my instructions. Why?
2. Even if it were ordered according to the `langid` field, the ordering option I used, namely `direction`, allows for only two alternatives: `ascending`, and `descending`. This is sufficient if there are only two `langid` values in use, as in my simple example. But what if there are more than two values, say `english`, `hebrew`, and `norwegian`, and I'd like the `hebrew` entries to precede both the `english` and the `norwegian` ones?

Comment: define a new sorting template with `\DeclareSortingTemplate`, see 4.5.6 Sorting in the biblatex documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried it. It didn't work. I've updated my post with the results of my failed attempt.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268384/35864.

Comment: All your `langid` fields in the `.bib` file are missing the curly braces around the values. Unless you have matching `@string` definitions this will not work (and should have produced warnings along the lines of `WARN - BibTeX subsystem: ..., line 9, warning: undefined macro "english"`)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution was inspired by [the post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268410/21685) which moewe linked to in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666182/how-to-sort-a-biblatex-bibliography-by-language-as-indicated-by-a-field-in-the?noredirect=1#comment1656534_666182). I have simplified meowe's code and changed its logic a little in the following way.

moewe's code imposes a total order on the set of `langid` values consisting of the values `russian`, `greek`, and `english`. Bibliographic entries whose `langid` is `russian` will be grouped first, then all `greek` entries, and finally all `english` entries.

In contrast, my code specifies a partial order on the set of *all possible* `langid` values. Bibliographic entries whose `languid` is `gibberish` will be grouped first, and then all the other entries.

The logic makes use of the fact that, unless explicitly specified, a bibliographic entry's `preorder` field is automatically set to `mm`, as specified in the second paragraph of section 3.6 'Sorting Options' of the `biblatex` manual v.3.18b, July 12, 2022.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap {
   \maps {
      \map {
         \step [
            fieldsource=langid,
            match=gibberish,
            fieldset=presort,
            fieldvalue=a
         ]
      }
   }
}
\addbibresource{TestBib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{a}\cite{b}\cite{c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When the following BibTeX listing is saved in `~/TestBib.bib`

```
@book{a,
   author = {a},
   title = {a},
   year = {0},
   langid = {english}
}
@book{b,
   author = {b},
   title = {b},
   year = {0},
   langid = {gibberish}
}
@book{c,
   author = {c},
   title = {c},
   year = {0},
   langid = {jibberish}
}
```

the PDF file resulting from executing

```
\> cd ~  
\> lualatex Test  
\> biber Test  
\> lualatex Test
```

displays thus:

[image: Bibliogrpahic entries whose languid is "gibberish" appear first.]